# Spin operators in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin

I'm reading for my exam on Monday. In my notes I have written that the teacher has told us that:

$S_1 \cdot S_2 = [(S_1 + S_2)^2 - S_1^2 - S_2^2]/2 = S_{tot}^2 - \frac{3 \hbar^2}{4}$
Where $S_i = (S_i^x + S_i^y + S_i^z), i \in {1, 2}$ and $S_{tot^2} = (S_1 + S_2)$.

It's the last equality I don't understand. I can see that $(S_1 + S_2)^2 = S_{tot}^2$, but how does $-\frac{S_1^2 - S_2^2}{2} = - \frac{3 \hbar^2}{4}$?

Comment: $-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(1+ \frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(1+ \frac{1}{2}\right)\right) = -3/4$... two spin-$1/2$ particles.